# Can't open grub menu through Shift or Esc keys

Tags: grub2

My laptop is double boot and whenever I start it , it always takes me to Windows regardless of pressing shift or anything(it worked well 1 month - grub was opening with shift but now it isn't).

Comment: i suggest you have a look at boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Maybe this might help you, to get you grub to work again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked for me :

1. Goto your BOOT menu and then go to BOOT settings - change "BOOT MODE" to "Legacy" from "UEFI" --> Save
2. Shut Down and restart.
3. In my case, it showed "No operating system found"
4. Quick shut down your system(by pressing the power button continuously for 15 secs)
5. Goto the Boot menu again and reverse the Boot mode back to UEFI.
6. Restart your System. This time most probably the GRUB menu will appear.

Comment: Great to hear. I would suggest that you check https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI - there you find instructions on how to install Ubuntu in UEFI or Legacy mode and how to convert them vice versa for future installations.